# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-charts, bridging-header

I am finding the following error while I am trying to Run my project with iOS charts library. The code works fine on Simulator when running on iPhone5 and iPad2 but build fails for iPhone6 and above:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC6Charts12BarChartData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SMWBarChartsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SMWBarGraphViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC6Charts12PieChartData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SMWPieChartsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC6Charts15BarChartDataSet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SMWBarChartsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SMWBarGraphViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC6Charts15PieChartDataSet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SMWPieChartsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC6Charts17BarChartDataEntry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SMWBarChartsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SMWPieChartsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in SMWBarGraphViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS symbols not found for architecture i386](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230040/ios-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386)

Comment: I have seen this link. It does not help me. I tried all things on this link but nothing works.

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Can you check the corresponding .m files are added in the "Compile Sources" in the "Build Phases" of your target. Normally, it gets added but if its not there, try adding them and then clean & build.

Comment: @neha_sinha19 : They are already there. I removed them and again added them but still got errors. But if this would be the problem then why Would the code run on iPhone5 and iPad2?

Comment: @NikhilGupta: what is the library? If you provide a link, I can look into it, to see what's causing the error.

Comment: @Sheamus : The library name is iOS Charts. [https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue. I included arm64 in valid architecture. The problem was that I was trying to integrate this library to already existing objective c project. Earlier was using core plot. So the core plot files were creating the problem. If core plot files were included then, I could not include arm64 in valid architecture due to which it crashed on iPhone6. So I just removed the core plot files and everything started working smoothly.