# How to link a library to an project in Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode4.5, static-libraries

I wanted to add JSScrollableTabBar framework https://github.com/jasarien/JSScrollableTabBar to my project in Xcode 4.5 but its help may be used for old version of Xcode

I also tried these helps
[XCode 4.3: Static Library Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655931/xcode-4-3-static-library-generation?rq=1) but it still did not work ! I couldn't import JSScrollableTabBar header to my code !!!

Comment: "It still didn't work" is not a good explanation. This question is worded poorly. Please update it to include what you did, what the expected behavior was, and what the observed behavior was.

Comment: yeah thank u. That meant I couldn't import JSScrollableTabBar.h to my code !!!

Comment: Did your monitor catch on fire when you wrote #import JSScrollableTabBar.h? Did you receive a compile time error? What was the error? Please review this FAQ about how to ask questions: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

am using Xcode 4.6.1 This is how I link external libraries / Frameworks

1. Select the folder navigation view on the top left corner [ you can see a folder symbol ]
2. Select the Frameworks folder - You will be able to see the libraries and Frameworks already linked.
3. Once you hit on the folder we can see the Targets window in the middle of the screen.
4. You will be able to see the linked framework and library section in the Summary  [ first ] pane.
5. Hit on the + symbol
6. Select "Add Other" button if your Framework is not listed already.

Hope this helps!!