# Xcode doesn't hit breakpoint when debugging on device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm trying to debug a certain method, but my breakpoints in that method never get hit when I'm debugging on a device, but they do get hit when I am debugging with the iOS simulator.  The method is part of a library that my app calls, and I feel like that may be a factor.  I developed both the app and the library, and I have both the app and the library open in the same Workspace when I'm debugging.

I put one breakpoint in on the line in my app's code that calls the library method, then a second breakpoint on the first line of the library.  When I test with the simulator, both are hit.  When I test on a device, only the first one is hit, and the second one gets skipped over (the code for the library method still appears to run).

Is there anything special I need to do to be able to step into a library call when I'm debugging on a device that I don't need to do when debugging on the simulator?  Or is it impossible to debug inside a library?

I'm sorry if this is a little unclear - I'm trying to describe what I'm doing as well as I can, but it's pretty strange behavior that I haven't seen before, so it's a little hard to describe.  If you need anymore information or anything is unclear, please let me know.

---

EDIT 1: I noticed something that's a little different, not sure if it's connected or not:  I don't have a .h file containing the methods in my library.  Actually, there is only 1 method in it (which I'll call`myMethod`) that will be called from outside the library (then that method calls the other methods in the library as it needs them).  Furthermore, I'm using the `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` pre-processor trigger to make the call in a slightly different manner depending on if it's running on a device or on the simulator.  To make the call into the library, on a button click method in my app I just have

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    extern void myMethod();
    myMethod();
#else
    extern void myMethod(const char diretory[], int directoryLength);
    const char *dir = [[documents path] UTF8String];
    myMethod(dir, [[documents path] length]);
#endif
```

I have matching `#if` blocks in the method in my library to declare it as needed, and to use `dir` when it is passed in.  This seems to execute just fine.  I can tell the code in my library is being called and doing something, it's just not doing what I want it to.  Thus the attempts to put in a breakpoint, and the reason for this whole question.

---

EDIT 2: My library actually contains plain C code, not Objective-C.  I put some `printf` lines into the library code, and its not being displayed.  I'm curious if somehow my app is calling a previous version of my library, instead of calling the one that's open in my workspace.  That would be consistent with the "it's just not doing what I want it to" part of my last edit.  Would it be possible that the device is trying to run an old version of the library it has saved somehow?  I thought that completely removing the app from the device before installing the new version of my app would prevent that, but perhaps I'm mistaken?

Comment: Have you tried removing the app from the device and retrying? I've had issues where bundled files aren't automatically updated on a device, and maybe the files on the device don't currently have debug info.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: yeah, I fully removed the app from the device, then I updated it by plugging it into my Mac and having Xcode run it on the device - that should automatically put the debug info in I would imagine, correct?

Comment: Yes, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: You also may need to "clean" your project (and then delete/reinstall on the device).  But understand that optimization can do strange things with debugability.  Sometimes you have to put the stop early and step through the code, et al.

Comment: @HotLicks: I tried that too.  I put the stop just before the call to my library, then tried to "step into" the library call, but it goes to a bunch of strange code that I didn't write (I think it's got a big hex tag before it).  I stepped through that for a while hoping that it would make it back to the code I wrote, but it never seemed to. After a while I used the "step out", and that brought me back to the code in my app after the call to the library completes.  I never hit any of the code in the library itself (at least not in the form I wrote it).

Comment: Are you sure some of your code is not compiled as a separate library module?  You generally cannot set breakpoints in such code.

Comment: @HotLicks: Not sure I know what you mean my "separate library module" The code I'm trying to put breakpoints in is part of a library that I added to my app's Workspace (following the method in idz's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655931/xcode-4-3-static-library-generation?rq=1)).  The breakpoints function fine when I debug on the simulator, they are only skipped when I try to debug on a device.